# Batch file to check time stamp of a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, timestamp

I am looking for a batch file script that can check the last modified time stamp of a file in a folder and check if it belongs to the current month & year.

I may have to check for multiple files in a single batch.
If it satisfies this condition, I need the batch file to copy them into a different folder.

Really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: `for /?` or `forfiles /?` or `xcopy /?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
mkdir "someNewFolder"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "compareDate=%dt:~0,6%"
FOR %%i IN (*) DO (
    for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=-: " %%g in ("%%~ti") do if "%%h%%g"=="!compareDate!" copy "%%i" "someNewFolder\%%~nxi"
    )
pause
```

**EDIT**

This should also work...

```
echo D | xcopy "." "someNewFolder" /D:02-01-2016 /Y
```

Or, not hardcoded:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
echo D | xcopy "." "someNewFolder\." /D:%MM%-01-%YYYY% /Y
```

**EDIT 2** To only copy files with a certain name from a certain directory use this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
echo D | xcopy "C:\Directory\Filename.*" "C:\someNewFolder" /D:%MM%-01-%YYYY% /Y
```

Or

```
echo D | xcopy "C:\Directory\Filename.*" "C:\someNewFolder" /D:02-01-2016 /Y
```

So something like this for your four different files:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
echo D | xcopy "C:\ABC.txt" "C:\myname\Destination_folder" /D:%MM%-01-%YYYY% /Y
echo D | xcopy "C:\GHR.xls" "C:\myname\Destination_folder" /D:%MM%-01-%YYYY% /Y
echo D | xcopy "C:\DEF.csv" "C:\myname\Destination_folder" /D:%MM%-01-%YYYY% /Y
echo D | xcopy "C:\XYZ.txt" "C:\myname\Destination_folder" /D:%MM%-01-%YYYY% /Y
```

**EDIT 3**

And finally, a script that allows drag and drop of all files you want to check:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
:loop
if "%~1"=="" goto :end
echo D | xcopy "%~1" "someNewFolder" /D:%MM%-01-%YYYY% /Y
shift
goto :loop
:end
pause
```

You can use this by dragging the files on top of the .bat file

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply. Just a question here. If I want to have exact folder path with file name and say I have some 4 different files with different extensions in this path, how can i mention those specific details? Example: C:\ABC.txt ; C:\DEF.csv C:\GHR.xls ; C:\XYZ.txt have to check these names exactly and move them to C:\myname\ folder!

Comment: Could you clarify with an example? You want to copy only files in a certain folder with a certain name, but with different extensions?

Comment: There will be so many other files too in this folder which is the reason why I need it to be specific.

Comment: INPUT files:
C:\ABC.txt 
C:\DEF.csv 
C:\GHR.xls
C:\XYZ.txt

These exact files have to be checked based on their timestamp. The check has to be if tis files belong to FEB 2016 (crrent month & year).
If yes, then, these files alone have to be copied from C:\ (source) to C:\myname\ (Destination) folder.

Once done, a message saying SUCCESS/FAILURE would be nice with how many files got copied.

Comment: So they all have different filenames? Why wouldn't you just specifiy both filename and extension if you know which file has which extension?

Comment: Yes.. different file names.

Comment: The thing is this script needs to be specific as I may be using it to pick different files with different extensions. If I just change the file name in this script, then it should be able to pick the new file. No need to change any extensions here after copying. Just a simple copy will do.

Comment: Yes.. The last option by you seems to work fine for me. Is it possible to hold the screen open without closing & add this part as weel: "Once done, a message saying SUCCESS/FAILURE would be nice with how many files got copied. "

Comment: @GaneshP just add `pause` at the end of the script, Xcopy already gives the succes message.

Comment: Cool.. Just observed something here. This does not overwrite the file in case it is already present in the destination folder?

Comment: @GaneshP added the /Y to overwrite files.

Comment: Awesome. Sorry for asking this. How to join that script for drag and drop of all files with the one you provided before that with individual file names? I know it's not a great one but pls bear with me.

Comment: @GaneshP You can simply change the directory name from `someNewFolder` to `C:\myname\Destination_folder`, but other than that it makes no sense to combine them. The entire point of the drag and drop one is so you don't have to hardcode the names.

Comment: Ok then. Got it. But where is the source folder name mentioned?

Comment: Is t like this? "%~1"=="sourcefolder"

Comment: "%~1" is the first file you dragged onto it, and shift shifts the order of the files so the second becomes the first. It does that until "%~1" is empty, so "%~1" is the name of the file to be copied.

Comment: @GaneshP If my answer solved your problem, you should consider clicking the check to the left of it so people searching on google for the same problem can find it. See [this](//stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for why this is important.

Comment: Ok.. But still my question of where source folder name needs to be mentioned is open. Could you pls answer that as well??

Comment: The sourcefolder is part of the `"%~1"`. If you drag `C:\XYZ.txt` onto the .bat file, `%~1` will contain `"C:\XYZ.txt"`

Comment: Sure.. You mean drag and drop of the source file on top of the batch file. If I want to do for 4 files, I will select all 4 and do a drag & drop. Hope am right.

Comment: @GaneshP Exactly, you drag and drop the files you want to copy on top of the batch file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate it. Chose ur answer as the best!